# Java8 - Object Type - Dynamically add more property

Tags: java, dynamic, reflection, casting, feign

I want to get the header value from the reply of http call, store it in cache and use this value in next requests by passing it to header of the http requests in order to achieve sticky session. My project is in Java 8.

I have feign http client builder like this which decode using JacksonDecoder.

```
   public <T> T buildClient(Class<T> type, String url) {
            return Feign.builder()
                    .contract(new JAXRSContract())
                    .encoder(new JacksonEncoder(mapper))
                    .decoder(new CustomDecoder(mapper))
                    .logger(new Slf4jLogger(Constants.FFA_LOGGER_NAME))
                    .logLevel(Level.FULL)
                    .options(new Options(connectTimeout, readTimeout))
                    .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
                    .requestInterceptor(auth2FeignRequestInterceptor)
                    .invocationHandlerFactory(factory)
                    .target(type, url);
        }
```

The default decoder from jackson decode only body not header so I am implementing my own CustomDecoder.

What I want to achieve is get the value of the resonse.headers and map it to body or add the property in the object responseBodyObject dynamically after it gets the value from the mapper.

```
public final class CustomDecoder extends JacksonDecoder implements Decoder {
    @Override
      public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
          //Here the default decoder only decoding body.
          Reader reader = response.body().asReader();
          Object responseBodyObject = mapper.readValue(reader, mapper.constructType(type));
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how do I make it work"? What's not working in the current version? It would correctly type-check the object you constructed.

Comment: I want to Convert type "Object" to myclass object which is dynamic class. I get the following error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: tech.csp.api.ffa.GetAccountsResponse cannot be cast to java.lang.Class. I have edited the last part of question.

Comment: Do you always know what type `responseBodyObject` is supposed to be? If yes, then cast to that type instead of casting to `Class<?>` - that's wrong, obviously.

Comment: No, I dont know what will be the type. it is dynamic. Thats why I am trying to explore if it can be done in Java 8 to dynamically assign the class like that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "assigning the class". You don't pick the class in the decoder, you receive it from the outside context - endpoint code instructs you that it expects a particular type of object, and it also gives you what bytes it has for response, and then you're as a decoder expected to parse it into object fields. The way you did it now is fine-ish, but I'd personally introduced an interface with token setter and would set the token if `returnObject` implements that interface, rather than injecting extra parts into body object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it right, this is a case of constructed type having additional properties that should be populated from header. Then, there are several approaches here. First, the one I would prefer, is having a special interface kinds that your decoder knows about, and recoded objects can implement to receive the values:

```
public interface SessionTokenAware {

    void setSessionToken(String value);
}
```

And then in your decoder:

```
@Override
public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
    Object parsedResponse = mapper.readValue(
        response.body().asReader(),
        mapper.constructType(type)
    );
    if (parsedResponse instanceof SessionTokenAware) {
        SessionTokenAware sessionAware = (SessionTokenAware) parsedResponse;
        Collection<String> sessionHeader = response.headers().get("sessionId");
        if (sessionHeader != null && !sessionHeader.isEmpty()) {
            sessionAware.setSessionToken(sessionHeader.iterator().next());
        }
    }
    return parsedResponse;
}
```

When your response implements the interface, then it will get the session token value set by decoder without having to hack the body stream and adding anything to it:

```
public class MyResponseBody implements SesionTokenAware {
    private String token;

    @Override
    public void setSessionToken(String value) {
        token = value;
    }

    public String getSessionToken() {
        return token;
    }
}
```

Altenatively, if you don't like having separate interfaces for every kind of possible headers you would want to receive, you can make a catch-all interface and let every response implementation sort out headers itself:

```
public interface HeadersAware {

    void onHeaders(Map<String, Collection<String>> headerValues);
}


public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
    Object parsedResponse = ....
    if (parsedResponse instanceof HeadersAware) {
        HeaderAware headerAware = (HeaderAware) parsedResponse;
        headerAware.onHeaders(response.headers());
    }
    return parsedResponse;
}

public class MyResponse implements HeaderAware {
    private String token;

    public void onHeaders(Map<String, Collection<String>> headers) {
        Collection<String> sessionHeader = headers.getOrDefault("sessionId", emptySet());
        if (!sessionHeader.isEmpty()) {
            token = sessionHeader.iterator().next();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't like the latter approach for two reasons:

1. The response may get to see values of headers it has no business seeing, because it receives all the values instead of just what's needed for implementing a particular response POJO.
2. If you have more than one distinct hierarchy of session-aware responses (so no common superclass is possible) - you will then have to copy-paste the sessionId handling code into each of them, instead of having that code neatly located in the `CustomDecoder` class.

Comment: you identified the issue very accurately. it seems like you are adding interface to gain additional properties. But how to implement interface in the Object type returning from the mapper?

Comment: I don't have control over the mapper object to change or implement the interface. The mapper class is from jackson.

Comment: There's no need for mapper to change or add the interface to deserialized types - you can do it on the type you are deserializing. For example, from your exception, you have a `tech.csp.api.ffa.GetAccountsResponse` that appears to be in your control, and you can add an interface there.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I understood you. But I am not understanding how to do the returnObject to return the token value together with the original object value. 
From your  code : "parsedResponse instanceof SessionTokenAware sessionAware"

I see that you are expecting SessionAware to be implemented by parsedResponse but how I will implement this?  I am getting the Object type from mapper.readValue() always.

Comment: Also I am using Java 8.

Comment: In Java 8 it would be the same as in my code - you add that interface and change `GetAccountsResponse` class so it `implements SessionAware`. In controller it's a simple class cast - as you already did, but do `SessionAware sessionAware = (SessionAware) resultObject` after `instanceof SessionAware` check is passed. I'll update code in the answer if that'd make it clearer.

Comment: just tried your code, it looks promising but there is still a issue. it goes inside the "if" but doesn't assign the value in the result object after assigning the property with sessionaware set. The result object token value is still null. I think it is casting based on the value and not reference. Here is how i am doing it.

 if (parsedResponse instanceof TokenAware) {
      SessionTokenAware sessionAware = (SessionTokenAware) parsedResponse;
.............
             sessionAware.setSessionToken(sessionHeader.iterator().next());
}

Comment: Check very carefully what your `setSessionToken` method does. If it calls this method with the correct value, then it must be something with the value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here how I solved my own problem with the different approach. To copy the header value to the body, I ended up converting the response to JSON tree then adding the header value of sessionid/token to body then convert it back to object.

```
  @Override
      public Object decode(Response response, Type type) throws IOException {
          Map<String, Collection<String>> headers = response.headers();
          Collection<String> values = headers.get("sessionid");
          String value = null;
          if (values != null && values.isEmpty() == false) {
            String[] array = new String[values.size()];
            values.toArray(array);
            value = array[0];
          }
          if (response.status() == 404)
              return Util.emptyValueOf(type);
          if (response.body() == null)
              return null;
          
          ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          try{
            StreamUtils.copy(response.body().asInputStream(), output);
          } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
           
          }
         JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(output.toByteArray());
         JsonNode node1=actualObj.get("header");
         ObjectNode parentObjectNode = (ObjectNode) node1;
         parentObjectNode.put("token", value);
         Object returnObject = mapper.treeToValue(actualObj, mapper.constructType(type).getClass());
         return returnObject;
      }
    }
```